# div boundary jQuery

Tags: jquery

http://jsbin.com/ofudi4/3/edit

What this code does you can test for yourselves.

Now my question is if i would have another div-tag around , like a frame. How would i make #moveMe to just move inside the frame div? Checking for boundaries after each move, so the figure doesn't move outside the frame.

Anyone now how to?

---

*EDIT: Adding code from link.*

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    // Left
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
      $("#moveMe").animate({marginLeft: "-=100px"}, {queue:false});
       return false;
    }
    // Top
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
      $("#moveMe").animate({marginTop: "-=100px"}, {queue:false});
       return false;
    }
    // Right
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
      $("#moveMe").animate({marginLeft: "+=100px"}, {queue:false});
       return false;
    }
    // Bottom
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
      $("#moveMe").animate({marginTop: "+=100px"}, {queue:false});
       return false;
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="moveMe"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change from animating margin to animating left and top it's easier test conditions using .position()

test if it's less than zero or greater than the parent width/height - it's width/height.

if not, animate as usual, if so set to to the edge.

You should also look into changing the easing, the movement is a bit odd when you hold it down.

```
if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
  if($("#moveme").position().left >= 100)
  {
   $("#moveMe").animate({left: "-=100px"}, {queue:false});
  }
  else
  {
   $("#moveMe").animate({left: 0}, {queue:false});
  }
   return false;
}

if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
  if($("#moveMe").position().left <= 
      $("#moveMe").parent().width() - $("#moveMe").width() - 100)
  {
     $("#moveMe").animate({left: "+=100px"}, {queue:false});
  }
  else
  {
     $("#moveMe").animate(
       {left: $("#moveMe").parent().width() - $("#moveMe").width()},
       {queue:false});
  }
   return false;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ofudi4/5

Comment: yes, but if i have a <div id="frame"><div id="moveMe"></div></div>, that was what i wanted. inside the frame div. And how do i change the easing, i admit it is a little bit odd when moving.

Comment: .parent() should handle any parent element.  Though I should note the parent element should be either relative or absolutely positioned for things to work right. as for easing you would add it to the options {queue:false, easing:'linear'}

Comment: so basically i could just use your code directly and put in a div with a specifik width and height around the moveMe div and it should work?

Comment: yes, relative elements make it easy to change the html without needing to change the jquery

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ofudi4/7/edit looks like it was a missing $ and the 100 changed to 20 (which is fine it just needs to be changed both places, it set both to 100)

Comment: yes now it seems to be working, BUT, when i move it up and down, it just goes trough the borderline. when moving left and right, it is good.

Comment: I only made the changes to left and right, making the code changes to top and bottom should just take a bit of copy paste  (top instead of left)